# React- calling this.setState inside a method that requires 'this' already

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am using a for loop to iterate over my Google map markers using:

```
for (i = 0; i < all_professionals.length; i++) { 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.props.listings[i].lat_lng,
    title: this.props.listings[i].name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map:map
    });

  marker.addListener('click', function(){
    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
    selected = this.title;
    console.log(selected);
    this.setState({clickedOn: selected}) <<<<<<<<
  })
}
```

In the `addListener` method I am trying to run `this.setState` or `this.props.methodFromParent` for example `this.props.methodFromParent(this.title)`. How do I do so without interfering with the `this` referring to the marker. As expected, using `this.setState` would return an error stating `this.setState is not a function`. Binding the `addListener` method would return `this.getPosition is not a function`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the reference to the class instance `this` before the loop.

```
var self = this;
for (i = 0; i < all_professionals.length; i++) { 
  // ...
  marker.addListener('click', function(){
    // ...
    self.setState({clickedOn: selected}) <<<<<<<<
  })
}
```